# Does there exist a bijection $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}^+$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

Does there exist a bijection $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}^+$ such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$$ exists?

My guess that no such $f$ exists.

Comment: Two sets are numerically equivalent iff there exists a bijection between them.

Comment: If there is such an $f$ where the limit exists, the limit must be $1$ since you can show that if the limit is $<1$ then the sequence has an upper bound, and if the limit is $>1$ then the sequence has a positive lower bound. In either case, it cannot be onto.

Comment: If you take Cantor's diagonal enumeration of the rational numbers, then this limit exists and it is $1$. If I remember correctly this was a problem in some Putnam or similar competition. Or maybe they put it with the limit $\lim_n\sqrt[n]{f(n)}$. One way to see it is to bound [or compute](http://massimozanetti.altervista.org/files/mydocs/kthRationalNumberCantorEnumeration.pdf) the corresponding rational number as a function of $n$.

Comment: That's pretty interesting; However, the Cantor enumeration is not injective; This seems to be a problem since it seems like you need to remove quite a large number of terms from it in order to make it injective, which might mess with the limit. What do you think?

Answer (score 7):

Let us take any enumeration of rationals $q_1, q_2, \ldots$ and make a new one $p_1, \ldots$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} = 1$.

Let $p_1 = q_1$.

Now assume we already enumerated $m$ points, and $q_n$ is the first one (in $q$) not enumerated yet.

If $q_n > p_m$, let us take some $x \in \left(1; 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$ such that points $p_m x, p_m x^2, \ldots, p_m x^k$ (where $k$ is such that $p_m x^k < q_n < p_m x^{k + 1}$) are not enumerated yet. Such $x$ exists, because for each $i < m$ we have only finite amount of numbers $y \in \left(1; 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$ such that $p_m y^i = p_i$ for some $i$.

Let $p_{m + 1} = p_m x$, $p_{m + 2} = p_m x^2$, $\ldots$, $p_{m + k} = p_m x^k$, $p_{m + k + 1} = q_n$.

If $q_n < p_m$, then similarly choose $x \in \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}; 1\right)$.